# Should I be using both "rel=canonical" and "rel="alternate" within my sitemap?

Tags: sitemap, xml-sitemap, hreflang, rel-canonical, rel-alternate

I followed this setup in my sitemap that Google outlines on this page: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077?hl=en .

```
<url>
<loc>http://example.com/en</loc>
<xhtml:link rel="alternate" href="http://example.com/fr" hreflang="fr" />
<xhtml:link rel="alternate" href="http://example.com/de" hreflang="de" />
<xhtml:link rel="alternate" href="http://example.com/es" hreflang="es" />
<xhtml:link rel="alternate" href="http://example.com/en" hreflang="x-default" />
</url>

<url>
<loc>http://example.com/fr</loc>
<xhtml:link rel="alternate" href="http://example.com/fr" hreflang="fr" />
<xhtml:link rel="alternate" href="http://example.com/de" hreflang="de" />
<xhtml:link rel="alternate" href="http://example.com/es" hreflang="es" />
<xhtml:link rel="alternate" href="http://example.com/en" hreflang="x-default" />
</url>
```

**However, should I also be including a "rel=canonical" tag like the following?**

```
<url>
<loc>http://example.com/en</loc>
<xhtml:link rel="alternate" href="http://example.com/fr" hreflang="fr" />
<xhtml:link rel="alternate" href="http://example.com/de" hreflang="de" />
<xhtml:link rel="alternate" href="http://example.com/es" hreflang="es" />
<xhtml:link rel="alternate" href="http://example.com/en" hreflang="x-default" />
<xhtml:link rel="canonical" href="http://example.com/en" />
</url>

<url>
<loc>http://example.com/fr</loc>
<xhtml:link rel="alternate" href="http://example.com/fr" hreflang="fr" />
<xhtml:link rel="alternate" href="http://example.com/de" hreflang="de" />
<xhtml:link rel="alternate" href="http://example.com/es" hreflang="es" />
<xhtml:link rel="alternate" href="http://example.com/en" hreflang="x-default" />
<xhtml:link rel="canonical" href="http://example.com/fr" />
</url>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Where are you getting the idea that *rel="canonical"* is the thing to do? Canonical tags exist within HTML. I am not aware of canonical being for sitemaps. Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

It is always best to have a "rel=canonical" in the `<head>` of the HTML code in each page that you want the site crawled as. This means that if you are using a a separate site for desktop and mobile, and both pages point to the same content, always have the canonical link point to the address that you want the search engine to recognize and crawl. ie. www.example.org & m.example.org should both have a:`<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.example.org/">` in the `<head>` of each page. 
The same would be for www.example.org/music.html & m.example.org/music.htm
Each page should have a canonical link:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.example.org/music">
```

Search engine are well known to skip over sitemaps that have not been recently changed. That is why most are overlooking the `<lastmod>` and `<changefreq>` setting. They are basically saying, "I have this information, why do I want to see it again?" A sitemap is relevant, but your pages are priority.

To place the canonical link in both the HTML code and sitemap is overkill.

Comment: Did you even read the question? Where did he mention "same content on different sites" or mobile site etc. He has multi language site. Not same content at all

Answer (score -1):

The `canonical` and `alternate` tags IMHO should be used in the HTML of a page.

The sitemap should only contain the URLs that you want indexed.

So the sitemap should look like this:

```
<url>
<loc>http://example.com/en</loc>
</url>
```

All other URLs should not be included in the sitemap.

Comment: The way I created my **Sitemap XML** is based on what Google shows on this page https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2620865?hl=en

Comment: You didn't put this: `<xhtml:link`

Comment: Oh ok, yes in this sample I didn't include it but in my real sitemap XML I have it listed that way.  I updated this post to include this now so it looks right.

Comment: I think I will keep my **Sitemap XML** the way I currently have it; like I posted above in my original post.

Comment: However, I just noticed I don't have **canonical** showing on my **HTML** on my website.  Should I be adding **<link rel="canonical" href="https://www.domain.com/en" />** to my **HTML** and it will show the right information depending on the page the user is on?

Comment: @olimits7 To be honest, I do not know, but my assumption in this scenario is that the `<loc>` tag would automatically indicate canonical. And each `"alternate"` is for that particular `<loc>`

Comment: Like you said, the sitemap should contain the URLs that you want indexed. Most people want all language versions of their page indexed which is why alternate is specified in the sitemap.